# Pass JSON object to Web Method

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, json, asp.net-ajax

I wanted to shared something I learned today with you all. My question was:

Can you pass a JSON object from JavaScript code to a .NET Page Method? For example:

```
  var task = { 
    Title: $("#titlenew input", $(newTaskRow)).val(), 
    StartDate: $("#startnew input", $(newTaskRow)).val(), 
    EndDate: $("#endnew input", $(newTaskRow)).val(), 
    EstimatedHours: $("#esthrsnew input", $(newTaskRow)).val(),
    PredecessorsOutlineNumbers: $("#depnew input", $(newTaskRow)).val(),
    OutlineNumber: $("#ordernew", $(newTaskRow)).text()
  };
  PageMethods.AddTask(task, saveNewTaskCompleted, saveNewTaskFailed);
```

And if you can, what type of .NET object should my web method accept?

I found out that yes, you can pass a JSON object to a Page Method, and it comes across as a Dictionary(Of String, String). So my web method signature looks like this:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub AddTask(ByVal taskJson As Dictionary(Of String, String))

  Dim oTask As New Task()
  oTask.Title = taskJson("Title")
  ' all other accesses to the JSON object here

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a blog.

Comment: From the FAQ for stackoverflow: "It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question." You've not done this. Maybe rewrite it as question/answer.

Comment: My bad - should I ask the question and then post the answer separately?

Comment: You shouldn't have done it, perhaps, but I am glad you did...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout this article:
http://dotnetslackers.com/columns/ajax/ASPNETAjaxWebService.aspx

Decorate your WebMethod with [GenerateScriptType(typeof(Task))] then in client side you will be able to create task. then pass it as regular object to your server side method.

Answer (score 0):

A detailed answer for a similar question states that combining the JQuery & Json2.stringfy() can be used for sending complex type to Server-Side methods.

And on the Server Side, you will only need to put the required Type in the Method Signature

(ex. foo(MyType obj) { ... } )

[How to send JSON object to asp.net web service and process the data there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039634/how-to-send-json-object-to-asp-net-web-service-and-process-the-data-there)